# Will using redirects to combine content from several pages into one pages affect search engine ranking?

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, web-traffic

I am redesigning a gallery which has several different pages and want to make it just one page. I would take the content from each existing page and add it to this one page. I would use 301 re-directs to direct traffic from the old pages to the one page. Would this hurt the keyword rankings for the pages I will be redirecting at all? I have read initially traffic will change, bit then it should be back to normal after a few weeks once everything is indexed. My client needs some reassurance his current traffic won't be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

301 redirect is one of the most SEO-friendly redirects. It basically (*and theoretically*) tells the crawling robot that:

> This page has moved permanently to this other page. So please from now on change your indices and preserved rankings to this new page.

Look what Google thinks about 301 redirects [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me. I just hate making assumptions on how seo traffic is going to handle change. I am glad I am on the right track though!

Comment: @Amy well the whole point of SEO is optimization and (unfortunately) you cannot guarantee the behavior of search engines in most occasions. The only thing you can do is to follow and apply their guidelines as much as possible ( ~ try to be a good student); in this way you decrease the chances for being penalized and increase the chances for being rewarded. :)